# How to access a JavaScript object as an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, go, gopherjs

In GopherJS, members of an object are themselves objects (just as js handles things under the hood, ttbomk).

So when accessing a member, one gets back a `*js.Object`:

```
func makeRID(o *js.Object) string {
  // access the array of numbers in member RID:
  arr := o.Get("RID")
  // arr is now a *js.Object - not an []interface{} - which is what I actually need (and what the contents of the property RID really are...
}
```

the incoming `o` is a js object that was extracted from a JSON response from the server.  Its member "RID" is the array of byte values - e.g. `{ RID: [ 136, 210, 92, 97, 152, 26, 17, 233, 147, 147, 8, 0, 39, 223, 163, 7 ],` ...

I'm not googling nor seeing in the js Docs for gopherjs any clear indication of how to go from a *js.Object to a gopherjs equivalent of an js array, namely `[]interface{}`

Ideas?

`*js.Object -> []interface{}`

Comment: what type is this `RID` object in JS? Is it a string? Or is it a typed array? Or something else?

Comment: Try https://godoc.org/github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs/js#Object.Interface and then type assert the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woo-hoo - got it!
Thanks for suggestions :)

```
func makeRID(o *js.Object) string {
  // access the array of numbers in member RID:
  jsRID := o.Get("RID")
  // I know that the source object's RID member is an Array, so we can access it in gopherjs as:
  jsArray := jsRID.Interface().([]interface{})
  // ... profit!
}
```